# Hidden Service in Android?

Tags: android

i used the following source in creating a service 
http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/60.html

but the thing is, the mp3 file is running, but as soon as i terminate the application (The gui with the start and stop buttons) the service terminates too !

i dunno if i understood this correctly, but on android developers site it says the following

```
When a service is started, it has a lifecycle that's independent of the component that started it and the service can run in the background indefinitely, even if the component that started it is destroyed.
```

shouldn't the sound still be playing even after the application is terminated using any task manager?

sorry, im new to java and android at the same time.
thanks.

Comment: Can you share the code where you have references to the Service in your app? And also mention the functions in which you refer to them.

Comment: im just starting, its the same exact code from that link i provided (ServicesDemo.zip)

Comment: If you are terminating the application using stop button, then it will close the service as well (as per the example) . Post your code if you are still seeing this problem.

Comment: im terminating the application using android Advanced Task Manager, without clicking stop. and i didnt modify the sample code at all, i just compiled it

Comment: Have you checked the Settings -> Application -> Running services list ?

Comment: its there in the Running Services List under the main application name, as long as the application is running the service is running (and visible in Running Services) but as soon as i kill the main application using (Advanced Task Kill) it kills the service and its not visible anymore in the Running Services List !

Comment: Not sure if Advanced Task Killer is killing the service as well. Try one thing, don't use Advanced task killer to kill app, rather use Settings -> Application -> YourApp -> Force stop.

Comment: same, all im trying to do is a hidden service, like android keyboard, not visible on Task Switcher (thats what its called on windows when u click alt+tab) am i doing it wrong? or i have to make a diffrent project type for that?